# I'm looking for a risk analysis book with citations from academic backgrounds that focuses on shocks and the unknown. Looking for a Taleb alternative

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, risk

I'm less than ... enthusiastic about some of Taleb's claims regarding, say, the paleo diet. I make no comment on his political content, but I want someone more factual and hard, and less prone to controversy and drama. I make no comment on Taleb's content herein as all I am saying is that I want someone different from his style, yet deals with the same overarching and broad content.

I'm looking for a well-referenced popular risk book that deals with dealing with the unexpected and shocks. Is there such a thing? This book would ideally have (a) mirror(s) in mathematical language and risk analysis papers.

Taleb discusses statistics here:--
(https://econpapers.repec.org/article/besamstat/v_3a61_3ay_3a2007_3am_3aaugust_3ap_3a198-200.htm)

Content I have consumed:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassim_Nicholas_Taleb
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_analysis
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antifragility
- *The Black Swan*
- *Bed of Procrustes*
- *Fooled by Randomness*
- *Antifragile*

Comment: Interesting post.  You're interested in books dealing with the unexpected in areas beyond financial markets?  Psychology, geology, meteorology, political science, military history, .... ?

Comment: I apologize if this is not clear, but I mean generalist-risk analysis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_analysis

Comment: This doesn't look like it's on-topic here. I would ask this on the [economics.SE] SE site or the [quant.SE] SE site.

Comment: @gung 

See here:--
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_risk)

Then here is another field in which risk is discussed:--
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT_risk)

Comment: Berenson, Alex (2009-09-11). "A Year Later, Little Change on Wall St". The New York Times. "Nassim Nicholas Taleb, a statistician, trader, and author, has argued for years that...."

Comment: There are other questions about risk analysis and Taleb on this Stack Exchange sub-website about statistics.

* (https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=risk+analysis)
* (https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=taleb)

What separates this from the others? 

I am completely confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at Merton’s credit-risk model that came out in the 1970s:--

> > "The Merton model is an analysis model – named after economist Robert C. Merton – that is used to assess the credit risk of a company's debt. Analysts at brokerage firms and investors utilize the Merton model to understand how capable a company is at meeting financial obligations, servicing its debt and weighing the general possibility that the company will go into credit default. This model was later built out by Fischer Black and Myron Scholes to develop the Black-Scholes pricing model."
> >
> > “Merton Model.” Investopedia, 8 Nov. 2006, www.investopedia.com/terms /m/mertonmodel.asp.
>
> Read more: Merton Model (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/mertonmodel.asp#ixzz5BYlVjuFV)

This paper links Merton-models to probability theory.

> > Tudela, Merxe, and Garry Young. "A Merton-model approach to assessing the default risk of UK public companies." International Journal of Theoretical and Applied Finance 8.06 (2005): 737-761.
> >
> > Read More: Merton Model (https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219024905003256)

Comment: Can someone please kindly take a look at the second link and see if my claims are valid? I'll retract or heavily edit the answer if there are errors.

Comment: Please don't post tentative answers in the hopes of getting feedback on whether they are correct. That isn't how CV, or the SE system generally, is supposed to work. FWIW, I have no expertise on this, so I can't say.

Comment: It's not tentative. It took a lot of time to find this.

I just want others to confirm this to increase the quality of this answer.

Comment: What I meant by "tentative" is that you are seeking for confirmation from others.

Answer (score 2):

[Aaron Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aaron_Brown_(financial_author))'s [Red-Blooded Risk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118043863) might be interesting to you. It has lots of references for further reading, and the ideas extend beyond the world of finance. However, it may not have enough actual equations/proofs - if that's what you're after.

Also perhaps worth looking at is Peters and Gell-Mann's '[Evaluating gambles using dynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0585)'. Whilst focused on evaluating and optimizing 'bets' it provides a good background on the history of 'risk taking' and how a lot of it is perhaps being done incorrectly - ignoring of path dependence, conflation of time and state averages, etc.

Comment: Aaron Brown knows Taleb personally and supports Taleb's views. You can verify this by visiting his Quora page. https://www.quora.com/profile/Aaron-Brown-165

Comment: I was going to also suggest some work by Gerd Gigerenzer, but I think his views also align with Taleb's, although he's far less dramatic or controversial.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. :) It's just not what I am looking for.